# unix code inside perl

Tags: perl, shell, unix

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$dir="/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/Test/translations";
$dir1="/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/Test/dest";
`find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\`;
```

This line:

```
find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\
```

works fine in Unix but I am getting an error in perl:

```
Can't find string terminator "`" anywhere before EOF at test1.pl line 4
```

I am trying to copy all files in `$dir` to `$dir1` without the subdirectories.
Using perl since the script will do lot of other stuff which is easier in perl.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using a double-backslash \\ instead of a single-backslash \ at the end.

Comment: The backslash is used to escape characters.  In this case is it escaping the backslash.  if you wanted a backslash after $dir1, you need to place to in to escape the backslash.  So you need to have $dir\\ instead of $dir\.

Comment: `find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\ ` does not work fine "in Unix". `\ ` followed by a line feed means the command continues on the following line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is the escape character in Perl.  The `\` at the end of your `find` command is escaping the `` ` ``.  You need to escape the backslash with another one.

```
`find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1 \\`;
```

This will now fail with `find: missing argument to -exec`.  You're also going to need a semicolon on the end of the `-exec` part.

```
`find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1 \\;`;
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit was looking at my answer and accidentally clicked the wrong one.  They look visually similar, but your wording (thought it was mine) is much better and I went to improve it.

Comment: @vol7ron No worries. I can't figure out how to write a backtick in code formatting either. Ironically, escaping it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `` ` `` to insert a backtick (doesn't work in comments, though).

Comment: Thank you!I got the exact error message after adding the backslash at the end. The semi colon after exec solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, try changing:

```
find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\
```

To:

```
find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\\
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslash and special characters.  Once for Perl code and again for whatever other language (in this case your shell).

```
`find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\`;
```

In the above code, the `\` is escaping your last backtick ( ` ) in perl.  So your child shell execution is never terminated.  To fix this simply add another backslash, which escapes that character from being interpolated:

```
`find $dir -type f -exec rsync -a {} $dir1\\`;
```